# Xamarin for Visual Studio (2015) Breaking Bootcamp Windows 10 Sound and Wireless Drivers

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, bootcamp

My computer is an iMac 5k (late 2015)

I have an issue where my bootcamp install of Windows 10 has nonworking audio drivers and wireless networking drivers after installing the default selection of cross platform mobile development pieces.

On my system this is 100% replicable.  All i have to do is create a bootcamp install of windows 10 64 bit.  Install visual studio keep defaults.  download and install the Xamarin for Visual Studio keep defaults.

After rebooting the sound driver has a red circle white x.  Wireless networking has a red circle white x.  Both drivers report all is well but neither work.  I have tried reinstalling the drivers from the apple drivers... I don't recall the name of the drivers installer.

I believe this is something do to with emulator hooks but i don't know where to begin.

Anyone have any thoughts?

As a side note once installed an uninstall doesn't correct the problem.  Whatever registry edits are made are not undone.

Comment: Perhaps add some more information on which Mac you are talking about.

Comment: Yep, that should have been in there from the beginning.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I can confirm this happened to me too after installing Xamarin for Visual Studio - audio was no longer available and wifi said that no networks were available. OS is Windows 10 build 1511 x64, hardware is 5k (retina) iMac 2016. FYI running Windows Update also breaks it so I have this service disabled and updates blocked via group policy. Rolling back to the restore point prior to the Xamarin install resolved it. Will try the OP's suggestion about disabling Hyper-V.

Answer (score 2):

Hyper-V seemed to be the culprit.

After going to "Windows Features", unchecking Hyper-V and restarting the computer.  Both audio and wireless drivers are once again active and working.

Comment: Unchecking Hyper-V resolved the problem! Thank you for posting this follow up answer Larry.